# CSS fixed top bar keeps coming down when testing my web base app on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, position

I'm working on a web base app for my school and using media queries to target different screen sizes. The versions for handheld and tables looks great.
However, when using mobile devices, every time I click on a button within the app the top bar comes down momentarily.

Position:fixed "works", and top bar stays visible if I scroll down on mobile devices. The issue consist on this bar randomly going down (center of screen) momentarily when I press buttons within the app. This problem persist on iO6 and android4.

here is a screen shoot of the app when the bar comes down right after sign In button is pressed:
[image]

here is the CSS I have for the bar:

Desktop CSS:

```
#user_session_box{
    color: #444444;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    min-height: 33px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 -15px 0 -5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
    }
```

Handheld/tablet css:

```
#user_session_box {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 45px;/*Must be px to display bg image properly */
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 30%;/*Android will murder logout button if padding less than 30%*/
    color: #FFF;
    font-size:16pt;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-image:url(../../images/bluebar7.png);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;/*Overwrites desktop margins*/
    box-shadow: none;/*overwrites shadows on desktop version*/
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Comment: Without an example to see it's hard to tell, but it could be something to do with the `position: fixed` you have applied.

Comment: Here is the link to it. http://as.sjsu.edu/vaishak/swpIndex.jsp

Answer (score 1):

position:fixed is not supported by the majority of mobile browsers. modern OS like iOS6 and android4 however do support it. -> catch the scroll event and reposition the element if the browser doesn't support fixed (use Modernizr to check that)

Answer (score 0):

This site contains an extensive research of the issue of fixed positioning for mobile as well as solutions to work around the issue http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/